# How to read SNI extension in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, squid, tls1.2

I want to find host name from `TLS Client Hello Message`. I want to find host name before java does complete handshake for transparent `ssl proxy`.

Is there any way to find `SNI extension` value without writing whole `ssl handshake` logic ?

Is Java supports `ssl handshake` with initial memory buffer ?
My Idea is:

1. Read TLS client hello message, parse it and find SNI value
2. Call `sslSocket.startHandshake(initialBuffer)` Initial buffer will contain TLS client hello packet data. So Java can do handshake.

Second Idea is to use `SSLEngine class`. But it seems a lot more implementation than requirement. I assume `SSLEngine` is used most of async in case which I don't require it.

Third idea is to implement complete `TLS protocol`.

Which idea is better ?

Comment: did you end up writing any code for this?  I am going down this path myself as I need it before the SSLEngine creation and even if I feed the first hello into SSLEngine, it still doesn't have the SNIServerName for some reason and returns a list of 0.

Comment: No, I haven't done anything yet. Priorities changed and this thing put in a backlog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both SSLSocket and SSLEngine lack (quite inexplicable) proper SNI support for server connections.

I came across the same problem myself and ended up writing a library: [TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel). It does not only that, it is actually a complete abstraction for SSLEngine, exposed as a ByteChannel. Regarding SNI, the library does the parsing of the first bytes before creating the SSLEngine. The user can then supply a function to the server channel, to select SSLContexts depending on the received domain name.

Comment: Yes, I ended with same solution. Parsed initial clientHello buffer and it did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer to this question is a bit old and does not really provide an answer to the question.

You should use a custom `KeyManager` when initializing the `SSLContext` and the trick is to use a `javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedKeyManager` (note the Extended term). This will offer the possibility to expose the `SSLEngine` during the key alias selection process instead of the plain (useless) socket.

The method `chooseEngineServerAlias(...)` will be called during the SSL handshake process in order to select the proper alias (cert/key) from the KeyStore. And the SNI information is **already populated** and available in the `SSLEngine`. The trick here is to cast the `SSLSession` as an `ExtendedSSLSession` (note the Extended term) and then to `getRequestedServerNames()`.

```
KeyManager[] km = new KeyManager[]
{
    new X509ExtendedKeyManager()
    {
        public String chooseEngineServerAlias(String keyType, Principal[] issuers, SSLEngine engine)
        {
            if( engine.getHandshakeSession() instanceof ExtendedSSLSession )
            {
               List<SNIServerName> sni = ((ExtendedSSLSession)engine.getHandshakeSession()).getRequestedServerNames();

                // select the proper certificate alias based on SNI here
            }
        }
    }
}

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(km, null, null);
```